# Why does print(list.sort()) result in None?

Tags: python, list, methods, printing

In trying to understand how to work with classes, objects, and methods, Please explain why `print(list.sort())` does not work like `list.sort()` followed by `print(list)`.

```py
list = [5, 1, 2]

print(list.sort())
```

#output is `None`

VS.

```py
list.sort()

print(list)
```

#output is `[1, 2, 5]`

Explained above: I expected `print(list.sort())` to output a sorted list instead of `None`

Comment: `list.sort()` does not return anything, therefore it returned `None` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation of `list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)

> This method modifies the sequence in place for economy of space when sorting a large sequence. **To remind users that it operates by side effect, it does not return the sorted sequence** (use sorted() to explicitly request a new sorted list instance).

(bold text by me)

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort()` does not return any value. `print(list.sort())` prints `None` because that is the value that represents no value.